# Visual Studio - Hide dropdowns underneath tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I open a .cs file in Visual Studio, underneath the tabs I have open are three dropdowns. They show the following tooltip messages when hovered over:

- Use the dropdown to view other and switch to other projects this file may belong to
- Use the drop to view and navigate to other items in this file
- Use the drop to view and navigate to other items in this file

Is there anyway to remove these dropdowns?

Comment: I don't want to remove them and knew they always exists. I thought "One day I may use it and improve my performance" but I never. But now reading your question, I think I may finally remove them! I remember the only time I find them useful is when modding games where there are hundreds of methods in a class.

Comment: @LukeVo I'm still learning to use the ide, but in massive classes I like to fold all the methods. Especially test classes that's always great. But I wonder if Visual Studio has a hotkey to view class methods.

Comment: There is a [Class View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/viewing-the-structure-of-code?view=vs-2022) but admittedly I rarely use it too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those three 'dropdowns' comprise the "Navigation Bar" and enabling/disabling its display is language-specific.

For your C# (.cs) files, you can disable the display as follows. From the "Tools" menu, select the "Options" command. Then, in the displayed pop-up, navigate to the "Text Editor" ... "C#" .. "General" node in the left-hand pane and then, in the right-hand pane, uncheck the "Navigation bar" checkbox:

[image]

To disable that bar for *all languages* in which it is supported, uncheck the control of the same name displayed when you have navigated to the "Text Editor" ... "All Languages" ... "General" node of the tree in the left-hand pane:

[image]